# How to instantiate class to a variable name?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment, and I have hit one roadblock. I am simply calling a string array from another class. The code in the other class (named ProductDB) is this:

```
public String[] inventory =  {"java", "jsps", "mcb2", "txtp"};
```

And in the main application class (named ProductApp) I have this code:

```
public static void showCodes()
{
    System.out.print("  Select from");
    System.out.print("  =>  ");
    for (String show : productDB.inventory)
    {
        System.out.print(show.toUpperCase() + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("  <=");
}
```

The error I am getting with `productDB` is `'Cannot find symbol'`  (I am using NetBeans).

I need to instantiate a variable named `productDB` correct? How do I do this within the `ProductApp` class level?

Comment: How would I call this method within main?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `inventory` to `static`, which makes it possible to call it in other classes by `ProductDB.inventory`.

If you want to use it as you are now, with an instance of ProductDB, simply create an instance variable in class ProductApp (which must be static, since your method is static).

```
static ProductDB productDB = new ProductDB();
```

Comment: its required that i keep inventory public. I did as you said, and im getting the error 'non static variable productDB cannot be referenced from a static context'

Comment: i just made my instance variable static and it fixed it, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3538320 - Ah, yes, I didn't realize the method was static, but I'm glad you figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

If your `productDB` is a class, you will need to declare the `inventory` member `static`.